# Can an appended file suffix to a parameter for file_get_contents be bypassed?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

Consider the following code

```
<?php
// warning: this code is unsafe and for demonstrational purposes only,
// do not use in a production environment
$filename = $_GET['filename']; 
$extension = 'txt';
$path = '/absolute/path';
$fullFilename = sprintf('%s/%s.%s', $path, $filename, $extension);
echo file_get_contents($fullFilename);
```

We all know (at least I hope so) that prepending an absolute path is by no way an adequate mean to prevent leaving the given path - one can simply insert one or more "`../`"s to the query string to reach any path on the file system.

**My question is: Analogously to the given example, can `$_GET['filename']` also be manipulated in such a way that the given extension suffix can be bypassed as well**, i.e. a file other than .txt is echoed? I'm especially thinking of certain control characters that bypass the appended file extension in the same fashion as `../` does with the prefix.

I tried adding some control characters (e.g. ASCII code 127 for delete) to the query string or concatenating two filenames by using `&&`, `|` or `>`, but all to no avail and I wondered if there exists such a possibility at all.

(Btw, I'd like to add the note that this questions is not asked for the purpose to exploit a system. It's purely a hypothetical question that came across my mind recently.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the `nullbyte`, `\0` (or `%00` if you want to test in a query-string), will have `file_get_contents()` stop processing the string when it hits it.

So, if `$_GET['filename']` is `../../../../../etc/passwd%00` (such as `your_page.php?filename=../../../../etc/passwd%00`), `file_get_contents()` will never see the ending `.txt` (it will see it, but won't process it).

Sadly, `sprintf` does not strip the nullbyte when building your string. I'm not sure about other control characters, but if anything - I would always recommend to strip the nullbyte. However, a more intuitive approach would be to build a whitelist of allowed characters and perform a `preg_match()` against the input.

Going one-up on that one, you can use PHP's [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath) on the built string and it will determine the full path that is really being accessed.
So, `/absolute/path/../../../../etc/passwd\0.txt`, passed to `realpath()` will return `/etc/passwd`. You can then do further validation on the returned value (such as, is the extension still `.txt` or is it within a specified/required directory).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, I didn't think of the nullbyte. However, I tried with `$filename = "testfile\0"` and placed a file at the specified path but `file_get_contents` returns `false` (Ubuntu 11.04, PHP 5.3.5). Is this environment dependent?

Comment: @moeso Not that I'm aware of; I tested with a copy+paste of your code and `$filename = "../../../../../etc/passwd\0";` and it worked fine (printed `/etc/passwd`). I can't find any documentation stating it's system/version dependent - but there's always a chance I've missed something of course.

Comment: Follow up: Just for fun I tried the same as described in my comment above with the only difference that i used the ancient, yet freshly compiled PHP versions 4.4.49 and 5.2.0 - and the nullbyte trick you described worked for both like a charm. So somewhere between 5.2.0 and 5.3.5 it seems like this hole has been closed.

Comment: @moeso Whoah - that's a good hint. I'll test that one out myself tonight!